# Use open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security still can not cross-border chrome in mac

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

Use of `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security` command still can not cross-border chrome  Please tell me How can I solve?

Answer (score -1):

try this command. it should work

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```